# How to send multiple arrays from servlet to jsp using sendRedirect

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I need to forward two arrays, processed by a servlet to a jsp page to display them. I have been successful in forwarding a single array using the code below:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    String n = request.getParameter("name");
    int k = Integer.parseInt(n);
    int array[] = new int[3];
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    List<RecommendedItem> recommendations = new ArrayList<RecommendedItem>();

    try {
        recommendations = App.getRecommend(k);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int i = 0;
    // out.println("we recommend");
    for (RecommendedItem recommendation : recommendations) {
        // out.println(recommendation.getItemID()+" "
        // +recommendation.getValue());
        array[i] = (int) recommendation.getItemID();
        i++;
    }

    String param = Arrays.toString(array);
    param = param.substring(1, param.length() - 1);// removing enclosing []
    String encArray = URLEncoder.encode(param, "utf-8");

    // Send encArray as parameter.
    response.sendRedirect(("output.jsp?fib=" + encArray));
}
```

But now I want to forward a second array composed of      `(int)recommendation.getValue()` to the output.jsp. Can it be done using `response.sendRedirect()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to send any String you want via parameters. In your case, just add a second parameter to your redirect with your second encoded array, like in:

```
response.sendRedirect(("output.jsp?fib=" + encArray + "&fib2=" + encArray2));
```

And get it in the same way you did with `fib` parameter.

However, a better and preferable way to handle the transportation of values in a Servlet would be via [RequestDispatcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html). Code for that:

```
req.setAttribute("fib", encArray);
req.setAttribute("fib2", encArray2);
req.getRequestDispatcher("output.jsp").forward(req, response);
```

And recover the arrays in the JSP using:

```
<% 
   String encArray = (String) request.getAttribute("fib"); 

   // ...

   String encArray2 = (String) request.getAttribute("fib2");
%>
```

> ***Note:*** With this second option you can even set and recover the Java array object (`String[]`) without needing to encode it.